Which approach suits for a problem where i try to find correspondance between two objectif of différent nature?
I struggle to qualify the problem i have and find suitable solution.
My problem is for exemple on one side i have invoices with amount due date invoices number and on thé other side i have transaction with a label , an amount , a banking code, a date.
I want to bé able to deduce which invoice match with which transaction. And in some case multiple invoice match with one transaction.
IS this a matching problem ?

I find that my problem kind be formalize to group based link prediction
